# Setting a property of an item in a list based on items in another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

Attention all list / LINQ lovers, I have a small challenge for you.

I have two list:

```
List<ObjectInfo> firstListObject;
List<ObjectInfo> secondListObject;
```

The first list is a list that I use to manage data. The second list I use to add items as the process goes on. So, from times to times, I will add / remove items on my list.

I have these fields:

```
public int m_ObjectID { get;set; }
public bool m_IsSelected { get;set; }
```

And my intention is that each time I "update" my `secondListObject`, I need to scroll through all the `firstListObject` to set the `m_IsSelected` value to true. **ELSE** the value must be `false`, meaning that if an item lands in the list the first time, then is removed afterward, the item's `m_IsSelected` goes false.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's what I have done so far:

```
foreach (var singleOrDefault in secondListObject
    .Select(objectInfo => firstListObject
        .SingleOrDefault(_item => _item.m_ObjectID == inventoryInfo.m_ObjectID))
    .Where(singleOrDefault => singleOrDefault != null))
{
    singleOrDefault
        .m_IsSelected = true;
}
```

Well, in a way, this works. It sets the item I am looking for to true. By default, all `m_IsSelected` value are false.

But if I remove the item, the `m_IsSelected` remains true, and that's what I need to do.

So, in a sentence: I need to make a loop in the `firstListObject` and check if there's any "occurrence" (based on the ID) of each of item of the `secondListObject`. If that's true, I'll switch the `m_IsSelected` to true. I just need to make sure that else the `m_IsSelected` is false, which I do not know how to do...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems have you run into in your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Again, your question is not clear. Are those properties member of `ObjectInfo` class or are they elsewhere? Can you express your idea using steps (1...2...3...)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble visualizing the question.

Comment: Oh god! I though my question was simple. :| I'll add up information in my post! Sorry!

Comment: Sorry guys, I hope this is clearer and, if it's not, feel free to tell me what you need.

Comment: So: if all objects in list2 are in list1, set all in list1 to true. If not, set all in list1 to false?

Comment: the *m_* convention isn't used for object properties. That's normally reserved for a module variable, if I'm not mistaken. I haven't used that in years.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano if any items are present in the secondlist, set all identical items in the first list to true, else those who are not present in the second list must be false.

Comment: @Yatrix is right the name of those properties is not quite right.
Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx it should be more like Id or ObjectId and IsSelected

Comment: Thanks for both of you, I know the naming is not quite right, it is just something temporary because of a small starting business. The whole thing will be made "right" eventually ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could first set everything to false and then just set the one that you want to true:

```
firstListObject.ForEach(o => o.m_IsSelected = false);
// your foreach goes here
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll dive into that. Sounds like this might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

So It greatly depends on what you are doing before this point.
If you had the firsListObject created without modifying it at all. Then the o.m_IsSelected of all the objects of the list will be in "false" because that is the default initialization value for booleans, unless you set them to something different.

Then you would only need to update the objects that have to be set to true.

If you have updated the list and modified what is selected and what not and you need to refresh. Then Kenneth option is good, then you could again just do your code after initializing all the values.

And you have a third option you want to update all the items in one shot. You could do:

```
foreach (var item in secondListObject)
{
    item.m_IsSelected = firstListObject.Any(x => x.m_ObjectID == item.m_ObjectID);
}
```

Comment: Well, at this point, consider that the first list is static and will not change, only the second list's content will change depending on what the user may select.

Comment: What about your secondListObject? Does the firstListObject have all the posible items of your system? And the secondListObject is going to always have a subset of items of firstListObject?

Comment: The firstListObject is a list that I use before reaching this stage. Based on search parameters, I fill it with data needed, so sometimes it may contains 20 items, sometimes 575, and so on. But when I used the second list the first list remains static as long as the program is not "rebooted", or the search redone. It's because the first list is a "browsing" category and the second is a "using" category, if you see my meaning.

Comment: Ok then, what you need to do is either reset the items to select=false, and then your code. Or directly the foreach loop I suggested that sets true or false depending if the item is found in the other list or not.